# Issue with updating webpage GUI

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I have a django site which is going to display various matplotlib plots. I am able to create a matplotlib plot, convert it into a png and display it,...but only if all the logic is contained within the views.py file of the relevant app.

This would be fine if I just needed a fairly basic page with a simple plot. However the problem is that the site as a whole is going to require several plots each involving their own python files, logic etc.

So what i've done is created a new folder within the app that contains the python files for calculating the various plots. From within the view.py I was planning on just calling the relevant python file which would return the plot. By doing that, I could keep the logic around how the plots are created separate from the displaying of the page.

The problem that i've run into is the following error

```
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
```

After researching this error it is clearly and issue when you are trying to update the GUI from a different thread. However that is not what im trying to do. Im trying to create the plot outside of the views.py file, then pass it back and create the png to update the page. So the updating of the GUI shouldn't be happening in another thread?

My code in views.py is:

```
fig = plotLogic.getPlot() #this is a call to a separate file which returns the figure
canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
response=django.http.HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
canvas.print_png(response)
return response
```

Is there an alternative way to accomplish what im trying to do? Essentially just keeping the logic of how the plot is created separate and returning the plot so that it can be converted to a png and displayed.

I feel like I am somehow making this more complicated than it should be. Im not intentionally trying to do anything fancy like updating the GUI in a separate thread.
Many thanks.

Comment: Oh no, it seem that I have either stumped everyone or I haven't explained myself clearly enough. If anyone has any suggestions or needs more information on what im trying to do, please share. Surely it is common to need to use existing python files and programs within django. You can't just put everything into views.py. Thanks.